# Turbo Tax says return was approved, IRS refund status shows processing

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, income-tax-refund, turbotax

After I e-filed my taxes through Turbo Tax, I signed up for the text notifications so that way I didn't have to keep checking the website/app.  I got a text message saying that my return has been approved and to go to a link within the IRS to check the [status](https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp) of the refund to get a specific return date.  After filling out the required information, it shows that my refund is still being processed.  Do Turbo Tax and IRS have different versions of approved?

Comment: Payments are never immediate. There is usually a "processing" step between "approved" and "check sent / direct deposit made."

Comment: yes I understand that.  First it went to processing, then a day later it said Approved.  But IRS still shows processing.

Comment: How much time passed between the time you got the text from TurboTax and the time you checked the IRS website?

Comment: within 24 hours.... I want to say about 20ish hours ago is when I got the approved text and I checked the site 30 mins ago or so.

Comment: TurboTax' _Approved_ means _Accepted as formally correct_. It always takes some days until the money gets paid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the IRS [Where's My Refund](https://www.irs.gov/refunds) page:

> Where's My Refund? is updated no more than once every 24 hours, usually overnight.

Try checking again tomorrow, and if it still says "processing," wait a few days, and check again.